# MX record on Win 2k8R2 not being recognised?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, mx-record

I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake here somewhere but I'm stumped where!

Trying to set up MX records for my domain (alpinered.co.uk) on the Windows DNS Server.

I've got an A record set up for mail.alpinered.co.uk. I've then created an MX record for host 'mail', FQDN 'mail.alpinered.co.uk.', priority 10. However when I test this setup using any of the DNS checkers I've found (intodns.com, for example), it insists there's no MX record present.

Are there any good tips (or references to setup guides) that might suggest what I've got wrong? Thanks :-)

Comment: You need to leave the host field empty when creating the MX record.

Comment: It seems you've only set up an MX record for mail.alpinered.co.uk. You probably want the MX record to be for .alpinered.co.uk instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you are not serving the MX record from the alpinered.co.uk zone.

```
dig -t mx alpinered.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.5 <<>> -t mx alpinered.co.uk
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28902
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;alpinered.co.uk.               IN      MX

;; Query time: 25 msec
```

You are serving it from the mail.alpinered.co.uk zone though.

```
 dig -t mx mail.alpinered.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.5 <<>> -t mx mail.alpinered.co.uk
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39730
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.alpinered.co.uk.          IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.alpinered.co.uk.   3600    IN      MX      10 mail.alpinered.co.uk.

;; Query time: 6 msec
```